# Optimal way to remove columns by condition in data.table

Tags: r

I've been learning about the data.table package in R and was trying to pre-process some data for modeling.

With data frames, one cam do the following to remove columns with little variation and those with strong correlation.

```
model_dat2 = final_model_dat[ , c(numeric_features)]

model_dat3 <- model_data2[,-nearZeroVar(model_data2)]

correlations <- cor(model_dat3)

highCorr <- caret::findCorrelation(correlations, cutoff=0.90, verbose=TRUE, names=FALSE)

model_dat4 <- model_dat3[, -highCorr]
```

I was trying to apply these general steps with data.table and it isn't as straight forward.

```
model_dat2 = final_model_dat[ , c(numeric_features), with=FALSE]

model_dat3 = Filter(var, model_dat2)

correlations <- cor(model_dat3)

highCorr <- caret::findCorrelation(correlations, cutoff=0.90, verbose=TRUE, names=FALSE)

model_dat4 <- model_dat3[, (highCorr) := NULL]
```

This "works"...but I was wondering what was the optimal way to remove columns by condition. How would the data.table solution to this task look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want to use the `nearZeroVar` on `data.table`, get the column names that have near zero variance with `nearZeroVar` and remove the columns with `setdiff`

```
library(caret)
library(data.table)
data(BloodBrain)
setDT(bbbDescr)
model_dat3 <- bbbDescr[, setdiff(names(bbbDescr), 
                     nearZeroVar(bbbDescr, names = TRUE)), with = FALSE]
correlations <- cor(model_dat3)
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
bbbDescr %>%
  select_at(vars(-one_of(nearZeroVar(., names = TRUE)))) %>%
  cor(.) %>%
  {i1 <- caret::findCorrelation(., cutoff=0.90, verbose=TRUE, names=FALSE)
  .[,-i1]}
```